# db value becomes null or even on indexdb open it does not go into onsuccess or upgradeneeded functions

Tags: javascript

```
(function () {

    var db;

    function openDB(dbname, dbtable, keypath) {
        var version = 1;

        // open the database
        var indexeddb_request = indexedDB.open( dbname, version ); // connect + open database

        // if error
        indexeddb_request.onerror = function ( event ) {
            console.log( event.target );
            console.trace();
        }

        // if success
        indexeddb_request.onsuccess = function ( event ) {
            console.log( event.target );
            console.trace();
            db = event.target.result;
        }

        // if onupgradeneeded
        indexeddb_request.onupgradeneeded = function( event ) {
            console.log( event.target );
            console.trace();
            db = event.target.result;
            var objectStore = db.createObjectStore( dbtable, { keyPath: 'url' } );
        }

    }

    function getObjectStore(store_name, mode) {
        var tx = db.transaction(store_name, mode);
        return tx.objectStore(store_name);
    }

    function addPublication(dbtable, data) {
        console.log("addPublication arguments:", arguments);

        var store = getObjectStore(dbtable, 'readwrite');
        var req;
        try {
            for (var i in data) {
                req = store.add(data[i]);
            }
          //req = store.add(data);
        } catch (e) {
          if (e.name == 'DataCloneError')
            displayActionFailure("This engine doesn't know how to clone a Blob, " +
                                 "use Firefox");
          throw e;
        }
        req.onsuccess = function (evt) {
          console.log("Insertion in DB successful");
        };
        req.onerror = function() {
          console.error("addPublication error", this.error);
        };
    } 

    function displayPubList(store, store_name) {
        console.log("displayPubList");

        if (typeof store == 'undefined')
          store = getObjectStore(store_name, 'readonly');


        var req;
        req = store.count();
        // Requests are executed in the order in which they were made against the
        // transaction, and their results are returned in the same order.
        // Thus the count text below will be displayed before the actual pub list
        // (not that it is algorithmically important in this case).
        req.onsuccess = function(evt) {
           console.log("Count of records " + evt.target.result +
                         ' record(s) in the object store.');
        };
        req.onerror = function(evt) {
          console.error("add error", this.error);
        };

        var i = 0;
        req = store.openCursor();
        req.onsuccess = function(evt) {
          var cursor = evt.target.result;

          // If the cursor is pointing at something, ask for the data
          if (cursor) {
            console.log("displayPubList cursor:", cursor);
            req = store.get(cursor.key);
            req.onsuccess = function (evt) {
              var value = evt.target.result;
              console.log("Key :" + cursor.key + 'value :' + value.ssn );
            };

            // Move on to the next object in store
            cursor.continue();

            // This counter serves only to create distinct ids
            i++;
          } else {
            console.log("No more entries");
          }
        };
    }

    openDB("abc","names","ssn");

    const customerData = [
      { ssn: "444-44-4444", name: "Bill", age: 35, email: "bill@company.com" },
      { ssn: "555-55-5555", name: "Donna", age: 32, email: "donna@home.org" }
    ];

    addPublication("names",customerData);

    displayPubList("abc","names");

})();
```

I'm trying to test the above code from chrome developer tools. But looks like some cases the call goes into sucess or upgradeneeded. And many times its always null. Please let me know if i'm doing something wrong here.